# GCC, C-project and GDI+

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gcc, gdi+

So, I have project written on C and need to draw PNG in the window created by the WinApi. I decided to use GDI+ and to create one c++ source file, linked to general project. There it is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

void drawPNG (HWND hwnd, unsigned xpos, unsigned ypos, char * rid) {

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC dc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);

    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    Rect rect(20,20,50,50);
    Graphics grpx(dc);
    Image* image = new Image(L"SomePhoto.png");
    grpx.DrawImage(image,rect);

    delete image;

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

}
```

I try to compile it with:

```
gcc -lstdc++ -x c++ img_drawing.c -lgdiplus -mwindows
```

And got these errors:

```
img_drawing.o:img_drawing.c:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `GdiplusStartup@12'
img_drawing.o:img_drawing.c:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to `GdiplusShutdown@4'
img_drawing.o:img_drawing.c:(.text$_ZN7Gdiplus11GdiplusBasenwEj[__ZN7Gdiplus11GdiplusBasenwEj]+0xfffffa09): undefined reference to `GdipAlloc@4'
```

But if I try to use g++, it builds without errors:

```
g++ img_drawing.c -lgdiplus -mwindows
```

I use MinGW compiler on Windows 7. Any idea why it's compiling with errors with the first command?

Comment: `gcc` is the c-compiler, do you have plain c-code? No.

Comment: No, I have C++ code, but gcc can compile c++ code with special flags (-x c++). If I remove GDIPlus functions it builds without errors.

Comment: Looks like the `libgdiplus.a` was created using `g++`.

Comment: What should I do? Recompile libgdiplus?

Comment: _"Recompile libgdiplus?"_ Should help.

Comment: I dont know how) Where can I found sources?

Comment: Well, what's wrong about just using `g++`, as long this works?

Comment: But I have Pure C project, I dont want to write on C++. It's very big differences for me.

Comment: The source provided is C++. You say you don't want to write C++ but you already are.

Comment: In theory you should be able to *compile* your c files with gcc and your c++ files with g++ and then use g++ linker to bring them altogether.Doing a quick search I found an [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5430720/3857942) that may be able to point you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll read it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling C and C++ files together using GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430688/compiling-c-and-c-files-together-using-gcc)