# G++ and GCC compliling

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

How can I link plain c and c++ code together using gcc and g++.
I tryed this:

```
g++ -c test.c #C++ source;
gcc -c main.c test2.c #Plain c source;
g++ main.o test.o test2.o -o main.exe
```

And this: [Compiling C and C++ files together using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430688/compiling-c-and-c-files-together-using-gcc/5430720#5430720)

But application doesn't see any functions from C-source files.

```
main.c: undefined reference to `mainWndInit'
```

Comment: Do you use `extern "C"` to declare the C++ function that's called from C?

Comment: Are you sure that your C functions are imported via extern "C" in your C++ code ?

Comment: Note that you do not have to use gcc and g++ separately; both will automatically use C or C++ compilation depending on the extension.  They are in fact identical except that g++ when used as a linker driver, links libstdc++ by default.  You could of course call invoke the linker (ld) directly rather than using g++.